# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call // Twitter

Tags: swift, twitter, parameters, ibaction

I am creating an app that generates a diferent quote everyday. I wanted to give the user the ability to *Share with twitter* the quote that was given. I was able to get twitter to pop up with the tweet box, but the quote was not showing up. I tried to get that to happen and now, I get a constant error:

> Missing argument for parameter for parameter #1 in call

**Problem**:
I would like to be able to get the quote to fill the tweet box as it pops up after the user taps the twitter button

[image]

Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func shareTweet(sender: AnyObject) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
        Share(text:Quote).shareTwitter().characters.count{ sheet in self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)};
        let tweetShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        
        self.presentViewController(tweetShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    } else {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to tweet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is the **share.swift** class:

```
import Social
struct Share {
let text: String

init(text: String) {
    self.text = text
}

typealias ShareSheet = SLComposeViewController

func shareTwitter(count: Int, action: (ShareSheet -> ()), error: (UIAlertController -> ())) { // Returns either tweetSheet or alert view
    if (count < 140) {
        if (SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)) {
            // Tweets Quote
            let sheet: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
            sheet.setInitialText(text)
            action(sheet)
        } else {
            // Not logged into Twitter
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to share", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            error(alert)
        }
    } else {
        // Character Count is greater then 140
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Character Count", message: "Sorry this is too long to tweet", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        error(alert)
    }
}
```

Edit: Dec '21 Replaced image to omit name on project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `shareTwitter(count: action:)` function takes two parameters. You are calling it with no parameters. You are then trying to call trailing closure parameter on `characters.count`. I'm assuming that what you mean to do is this:

```
Share(text:Quote).shareTwitter(Quote.characters.count) { sheet in self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)};
```

I don't think you actually need the `count` parameter on your `shareTwitter()` function though. The `Share` struct already has the `text` stored in a property. Why not just use that?

```
func shareTwitter(action: (ShareSheet -> ()), error: (UIAlertController -> ())) { // Returns either tweetSheet or alert view
    if (text.characters.count < 140) {
        // Code removed for brevity 

    } else {
        // Code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Then you can make your function call like this:

```
Share(text:Quote).shareTwitter() { sheet in self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)};
```

---

Additionally, you don't seem to be returning another closure in your `action` closure. I think you mean to have your closure parameter returning `Void`.

On another note, because you are using two closure parameters, one for `action` and another for `error`, I don't think your code is going to compile even with that change. You would need to do this:

```
Share(text:Quote).shareTwitter(action: { sheet in 
    self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}) { error in 

}
```

When using a closure that may have an error, the best way to do this is to use a `Result` monad. It's not hard to implement this for yourself, but you can take a look at [antitypical/Result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) for a library that gives you a `Result` monad out of the box.

With both of those changes, your `shareTwitter()` function looks like this:

```
func shareTwitter(action: (Result<ShareSheet, NSError> -> Void)) { // Returns either tweetSheet or alert view
    if (text.characters.count < 140) {
        // Code removed for brevity 

    } else {
        // Code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

And it is called like this:

```
Share(text:Quote).shareTwitter() { result in 
    switch result {
    case .Success(let sheet): 
        self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)};

    case .Failure(let error):
        // Do something with your error
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just added it in.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the full intent of what you are trying to do now. My answer has been revised and should more than fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and explanation. The error cleared up immediately. You're awesome! Stay Awesome!

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear everything is working for you now.